# I can’t find this manga/webtoon isekai about a blond girl in a magic world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

It’s about a girl that reincarnated in a child blond (not sure that she is blond) noble girl. There is also a blond guy that because he has a particular color of eyes he can use magic. She took him because he’s an orphan and asked that he learn magic.

There is a thing about her knowing by who she will be killed. I don’t quite remember but I think it’s the prince of the country.